# Locating the query for WooCommerce Export functionality

Tags: sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I am looking to edit the query being used for the 'CSV Export' function within WooCommerce, I've logged into my phpMyAdmin section, and can't seem to make sense of it.

Could anyone help?

Comment: I think you have to look for wc_customer_order_csv_export_delimiter function in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for this in the future, here is what I came up with that got most of the values from the export csv function:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM
(
    SELECT
        pm.post_id as 'order_id',
        p.post_date as 'order_date',
        p.post_status as 'order_status',
        MAX(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_order_shipping' THEN pm.meta_value END) as 'order_shipping',
        MAX(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_order_shipping_tax' THEN pm.meta_value END) as 'order_shipping_tax',
        MAX(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_order_tax' THEN pm.meta_value END) as 'order_tax',
        MAX(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_cart_discount' THEN pm.meta_value END) as 'cart_discount',
        MAX(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_order_total' THEN pm.meta_value END) as 'order_total',
        MAX(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_payment_method' THEN pm.meta_value END) as 'payment_method',
        oi.order_item_name as 'shipping_type',
        MAX(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_first_name' THEN pm.meta_value END) as 'billing_first_name',
        MAX(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_last_name' THEN pm.meta_value END) as 'billing_last_name',
        MAX(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_email' THEN pm.meta_value END) as 'billing_email',
        MAX(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_phone' THEN pm.meta_value END) as 'billing_phone' ,
        MAX(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_address_1' THEN pm.meta_value END) as 'billing_address1',
        MAX(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_address_2' THEN pm.meta_value END) as 'billing_address2',
        MAX(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_postcode' THEN pm.meta_value END) as 'billing_postcode',
        MAX(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_city' THEN pm.meta_value END) as 'billing_city',
        MAX(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_state' THEN pm.meta_value END) as 'billing_state',
        MAX(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_country' THEN pm.meta_value END) as 'billing_country',
        MAX(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_company' THEN pm.meta_value END) as 'billing_company',
        MAX(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_shipping_first_name' THEN pm.meta_value END) as 'shipping_first_name',
        MAX(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_shipping_last_name' THEN pm.meta_value END) as 'shipping_last_name',
        MAX(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_shipping_address_1' THEN pm.meta_value END) as 'shipping_address1',
        MAX(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_shipping_address_2' THEN pm.meta_value END) as 'shipping_address2',
        MAX(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_shipping_postcode' THEN pm.meta_value END) as 'shipping_postcode',
        MAX(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_shipping_city' THEN pm.meta_value END) as 'shipping_city',
        MAX(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_shipping_state' THEN pm.meta_value END) as 'shipping_state',
        MAX(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_shipping_country' THEN pm.meta_value END) as 'shipping_country',
        MAX(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_shipping_company' THEN pm.meta_value END) as 'shipping_company',
        t.items
    FROM
        wp_postmeta pm  INNER JOIN wp_posts p ON p.ID = pm.post_id AND  p.post_type = 'shop_order'
        INNER JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items oi on oi.order_id = pm.post_id AND oi.order_item_type = 'shipping'
        INNER JOIN (SELECT order_id, GROUP_CONCAT(order_item_name SEPARATOR ' | ') as 'items' FROM wp_woocommerce_order_items oi1 WHERE oi1.order_item_type = 'line_item' group by order_id) as t ON t.order_ID = pm.post_id 
    GROUP BY
        pm.post_id
) as t
WHERE
    t.billing_email IS NOT NULL
```